# Lua for can't do the same as C for?

Tags: for-loop, lua

There is no way to do the same with the C for?

I mean put two or more variables as init, and increment

```
for (i, j, k; i!=100; i++, j*3, k++)
```

the lua for seems can't do this but maybe I'm wrong and there is a way to do that

```
for i=0, i~=1000, -1
```

I guess it's strange lua can't do that since lua has a lot of things to work better and simplify the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lua's `for` syntax is more restrictive than C's. If you want to do something complicated like that in your loops, you have to spell it out with a `while` loop or use a `for` loop with other increments done in the loop body.

You could also try to express this complicated sequence with an iterator. But for readability, it's best to avoid complex looping statements of this sort whenever possible.

Comment: Ty for the answer, I was hoping there it was a way to do. But meh, an other for is a good solution anyway. Just i were asking about because maybe there it was a way and i was missing it.